# How to remove back shadow in UIWebView while loading PDF in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am trying to display PDF file in UIWebView. Working fine. But, PDF view having shadow on back side. I dont know how to remove it completely.

**My Code:**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    for object in webView.scrollView.subviews
    {
            if NSStringFromClass((object.classForCoder)) == "UIWebPDFView"
            {
                let pdfVi = object

                for pdf_view_sub in (pdfVi.subviews)
                {
                    if NSStringFromClass((pdf_view_sub.classForCoder)) == "UIPDFPageView"
                    {
                        let pdfVi_lay = pdf_view_sub
                        pdfVi_lay.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**My Image**

[image]

The above code is not working when we start scrolling. That means, if we are trying to scroll upwards, automatically same shadow appearing on PDF's backside.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a similar situation. I need to change the border and the background color in Swift3 in a UIWebView only for PDF viewer, and it is important to keep another color for other files than PDF.

It is not the exact solution, but it is a solution suitable for your problem. Anyway this solution is useful for more scenarios.

Here is my solution:

```
    var color = UIColor.white
    for object in webView.scrollView.subviews {
        if NSStringFromClass((object.classForCoder)) == "UIWebPDFView" {
            for pdf in (object.subviews) {
                if NSStringFromClass((pdf.classForCoder)) == "UIPDFPageView" {
                    color = UIColor(red:0.502, green:0.502, blue:0.502, alpha:1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    webView.backgroundColor = color
    webView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = color
    webView.scrollView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    for object in webView.scrollView.subviews {
        object.backgroundColor = color
        object.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        if NSStringFromClass((object.classForCoder)) == "UIWebPDFView" {
            object.backgroundColor = color
            object.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
            for pdf in (object.subviews) {
                pdf.backgroundColor = color
                pdf.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                if NSStringFromClass((pdf.classForCoder)) == "UIPDFPageView" {
                    pdf.backgroundColor = color
                    pdf.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

New in iOS 12 and `PDFView` of `PDFKit` we have a property we can set to false

```
pageShadowsEnabled = false
```